# react-dom.production.min.js:171 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've searched through the entire web to resolve that recursive issue but could not find anything...
In the majority of the case, that issue occurs when calling setState() in didUpdate() function but it's not my case.

Initially I was using react v15, my app was working well on both
environments, development and production.

Lately I decided to upgrade to react v16, and also upgrade to node 8.12.0.

At this point my app was working perfectly fine when NODE_ENV=development, but when I deployed on production(NODE_ENV=production), I started to get that strange issue, thrown, in the console of my chrome browser

I've found out that if I downgrade react to version 15, my app started to work again on production.

During my investigation I've tested that, dispatching too many actions triggers that "Maximum call stack size exceeded" issue.

Why would my code works fine when NODE_DEVELOPMENT and crash when NODE_ENV- production ?

Could anyone give me some help?

Please find my code: ContainerPage.js

```
class ContainerPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const { locale } = props;
        moment.locale(locale);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const {
            getGeometry,
            getCountries,
            getNodes,
            geometry = [],
            location: { query = {} } = {},
        } = this.props;
        const { INIT_CORPORATION_TREE } = actions;
        if (geometry.length === 0) {
            getCountries();
            getGeometry();
        }
        getNodes(
            {
                action: INIT_CORPORATION_TREE,
                corporationIdQuery: !isEmpty(query) ? query.corporationId : null,
            });
    }

    render() {
        const { content,
            children,
            header,
            commonProfileSetup,
            selectedCorporation = {},
            riskConfig: { riskConfigInitialized = false } = {},
        } = this.props;
        if (!isEmpty(selectedCorporation.id) && riskConfigInitialized) {
            return (
                <Col md={12}>

                    {content || children}
                </Col>
            );
        }
        return <div>test</div>;
    }
}

export default withRouter(ContainerPage);
```

Routes.js

```
export default (
  <Route component={App} onChange={scrollToTop}>
    <Route path="/nui">
      <Redirect
        from={config.nui.baseUrl}
        to={config.nui.baseUrl + '/search'}
      />
      <Route
        key="locate"
        path="locate"
        component={NuiPageContainer}
      >
        <Route getResponseHeaders={() => ({ 'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY' })}
          component={UserIsAuthorized(ContainerPage)}>
          <Route
            path="search"
            getComponents={(loc, cb) => {
              require.ensure([], require => {
                cb(null, {
                  header: () => <Header titleId="title._dynamic.search" />,
                  //commonProfileSetup: () => <CommonProfileSetup pageReducer="search" treeReducer="corporationTree"  showTree />,
                  //content: ({}) => <SearchPage pageReducer={PAGE_REDUCER.SEARCH} />,
                });
              });
            }}
          />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Route>
```

Dispatch actions

```
export const getCountries = withJWT(
  createFetchAction(
    GET_COUNTRIES,
    `${RM_BASE_URI}/country/countries`,
    getOptions
  )
);


// Getting geometry from local file
export const getGeometry = () => {
  return {
    type: GET_GEOMETRY,
    payload: GEOMETRY,
  };
};


export function getNodes(param = {  }, actions) {
  return (dispatch, getState, parentState) => {
    const { selectedNode } = getState()[parentState];
    const {
      JWT: { token },
      routing: { locationBeforeTransitions: { pathname = '' } = {} } = {},
      userPrefs: { loginName }
    } = getState();
    const {
      FETCHING_NODES,
      RESET_TREE,
      HIGHLIGHT_SELECTED_CORPORATION,
      SET_CORPORATION_PROGRAMMATICALLY,
      SET_CORPORATION_FROM_DB,
      INIT_CORPORATION_TREE,
    } = actions;
    let url;
    url = `${config.nui.riskMessaging.uri}/corporation/default?concurLoginId=${loginName}`;
    if (!isEmpty(param.corporationIdQuery)) {
      url = `${url}&selectedCorporation=${param.corporationIdQuery}`;
      if (pathname.includes('details')) {
        url = `${url}&subLevelsOnly=true`;
      }
    }
    const { action = '' } = param;
    const onCompleteAction = action;
    const loadingAction = FETCHING_NODES;
    return fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          return response.json();
        }
      })
      .then(result => {
        const { corporationTree: { corporations } } = getState();
        dispatch(createAction('INIT_CORPORATION_TREE')(result));

      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log("Oops... " + err);
      });

  };
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue right now

Comment: @Athman this is related to react version

Comment: Thanks @jaybe78. I had thought so too when I downgraded to an earlier version and everything was alright. I was also using old syntax for `Helmet`. And `recharts` too kinda triggered the crash. My product build works without `recharts`.